Power BI compare attainment of students with historic norms
I have a table 'Attainment' that contains the following:
Adno = a unique identifier for a student (it's their admission number)
Subj = the code for the subjects being studied (eg Ma for Maths, en for English, etc)
Att = the attainment of the student in that subject at a certain point in time (eg 5,6,7 etc)
Date = the date the attainment was recorded.
This table is updated 3 times per year, with each student's attainment in each subject being logged.
I have another table 'HistoricNorm' containing the following:
Subj = the code for the subjects being studied (eg Ma for Maths, En for English, etc)
Gd = each attainment grade it is possible for a student to achieve (eg 5, 6, 7 etc)
PercentGd = the historic percentage of students achieving a particular grade in that subject
This table is static.
I want to make a 'Line and Stacked Column' chart so that:
The number of students achieving each attainment grade is shown as the column.
The number of students expected to achieve each attainment grade is shown as the line.
As the number of students taking a particular subject varies from year to year, I want to find the number of students expected to achieve each attainment grade in a particular year by multiplying the total number of students taking each subject by the 'HistoricNorm' PercentGd for each grade in each subject.
At present, there is no relationship between the 2 tables, as Power BI warns me about Many-Many cardinality. As I don't really understand this, it seemed obvious that something was wrong, hence the plea to you good people out there.
I've tried to create various relationships between the 2 tables, but this always warns me about Many-Many cardinality.
